# Add element in XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I would like to add some elements to my XML file, but I can't find the correct way to access the correct dimensions.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<params name="model.userFieldsFactory">
 <param key="userFields">
  <list>
   <params name="userField.map">
    <param key="userField.aggMode" short="5"/>
    <param key="fieldName" string="1360_5015"/>
    <param key="userField.tooltip" string=""/>
```

My new XML file with the new line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<params name="model.userFieldsFactory">
 <param key="userFields">
  <list>
   <params name="userField.map">
    <param key="userField.aggMode" short="5"/>
    <param key="fieldName" string="1360_5015"/>
    <param key="userField.tooltip" string=""/>
   <params name="userField.map">
    <param key="userField.aggMode" short="20"/>
    <param key="fieldName" string="11000_49389"/>
    <param key="userField.tooltip" string=""/>
```

My code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(path_to, "model.userFieldsFactory.xml"))
root = tree.getroot()
sub_root = ET.SubElement(root, "param", attrib={'key': 'userFields'})
list_dim = ET.SubElement(sub_root, 'list')
name = ET.SubElement(list_dim, 'params')
name.set('name', "userField.map")
```

Comment: you could use `xmltodict` module to do that.

Comment: start by updating you post with 2 VALID xml files. The current and the expected. Explain what need to be added.

Comment: Yes, i think is done

Comment: You should post complete XML files, not just fragments without proper end tags.